# How can I replace double quotes in nested quotes using php

Tags: php, regex, string, quotes

I have a dynamic string registered in the database by the rich textbox. Like this.

```
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-size:"
medium;">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT.</p>

<ol style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-size:" 
medium;"><li>BONUM VALITUDO: MISER MORBUS.</li></ol>
```

And I tried replace the double quotes in the `style` tag. But I didn't it. How can I it with PHP.

By the way. This string seems normally in the rich textbox but saving database  with nested quotes

My Rich Textbox is : `Summernote`

Comment: Do you always want to target the `font-family` attribute of the tag?  Or, could these double quotes be nested anywhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, could be the double quotes nested anywhere

Comment: you could of course use single quotes on the outside. or use a string replace (prepend with a backslash) Btw: your outer quotes are never closed.

Comment: This is hard to fix reliably. By extracting `style="(.*?)">` you could apply the appropriate escaping. Given the misquoting after font-size:, I would rather just search and replace known/fixed strings like `"Times New Roman"` or `"medium;` completely.

Comment: @Burki I must do only nested quotes backslash or single quotes. But I getting dynamic string from the rich textbox. I want to do each string replace. But I don't know how make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback()` to running regex. The code select content inside `style=""` and in callback function replace `"` with `'`

```
$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=style=\")([^>]+)(?=\">)/", function($matches){
    return str_replace('"', "'", $matches[1]);
}, $str);
```

Note that your style doesn't `'` for last part of style. So you can this code to adding `'` at the end of style.

```
$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=style=\")([^>]+)(?=\">)/", function($matches){
    $replace = str_replace('"', "'", $matches[1]);
    return substr($replace, -1) == "'" ? $replace : $replace."'";
}, $str);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/JD10n)